# Visual Studio 2012 can not start kernel mode debugging but Windbg can

Tags: visual-studio-2012, kernel, windbg, remote-debugging, device-driver

I'm trying do deploy and debug my kernel driver.

Host: Win7 Prof, 64-bit
Guest (VirtualBox): Win7 Prof, 64-bit Checked / Win7 Prof, 32-bit

I followed many tutorials but without success.
Vistual Studio claims:

> Unable to attach to the process

and

> Windows Debugging Extension for Visual Studio
>   Failure to create process instance prevents debugging

In the other hand Windbg can connect to the VM (with the same configuration) but only during restart of VM.

I'm totally frustrated because no single solution helped.
For eg.:

> http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/545835/Kernel-Mode-Debugging-in-a-VM-using-Visual-Studio
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I've tried to provision my machines but every time it fails at

> Installing .NET Framework (possible reboot)

and

> Installing driver test framework

What's more, when configuring new sample project in Visual Studio (NDIS sample driver) then I'm forced to add additional includes because it won't compile but as far as I know it should compile (plain sample project) without any additional configuration.

Comment: In my case after reinstalling system (VS reinstall didn't help) debugging works as expected. Unfortunately provisioning still not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I ran Visual Studio 2012 non-elevated. Choosing "run as administrator" fixed it.